# Homophone riddle 3

Tags: riddle, word

Here you go @PerpetualJ

```
To memorize or to see again,
It still will sound the same
You would do this for a concert
Or you might if you reread a book,
You would do this to all the pages
```

What are the homophones?

Hint

> There is a synonym for concert, and that is a form of the one of the words

Comment: I enjoyed this one; I made a homonym riddle, just for you! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Recite/Resight

To memorize

> *Recite* can mean repeat from memory.

or to see again,

> *Resight* can mean to see again.

It still will sound the same

> They are homophones.

You would do this for a concert

> A synonym for a concert is a **recit**al.

Or you might if you reread a book,

> Resight

You would do this to all the pages

> You would resight every page.

Comment: Correct! Obviously, I never made a hard one

Comment: @Duck, If this is the intended answer, the puzzle might need some work. For starters, the word meanings are a bit off: there won't be any reciting going on in a concert called a recital, and you'd have to be actively trying to find something hidden from view in order to resight it. Those are probably ok in a riddle setting (chalk it up to wordplay), but the bit about sounding the same is trickier: resight has a long first vowel, recite has a short one, so in order to make them sound the same, you'd have to mispronounce one or the other, which kind of goes against the whole point of the puzzle.

Comment: Sorry, when I made this puzzle I forgot to check the pronunciations

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> review.

To memorize or to see again,
It still will sound the same

> To review vocab for example, or to "view again"

You would do this for a concert

> Review a concert, as in give a rating.

Or you might if you reread a book,
You would do this to all the pages

> Review a textbook's material for example

Comment: Beat me to the punch here, but technically aren't you presenting the homonyms instead of the homophones? +1

Comment: @PerpetualJ Yes, I was uncertain about that. But it did seem like the different meanings worked out anyway.  Your answer is probably the correct one.

Comment: Based on the riddle itself, technically the homonym is a very proper answer. As for the homophone, it kind of works out in its own way. :)

Comment: Sorry but incorrect, close though

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is:

> Review and Revue

Based on:

> Review is what you do to memorize, scan pages, or see something again. Revue is theatrical entertainment consisting of a series of sketches, songs, and dances.

*To memorize or to see again*

> You would review something to memorize it, and to take a second look to ensure accuracy.

*It still will sound the same*

> Review and Revue sound the same.

*You would do this for a concert*

> You could review a concert, but a revue is also a concert of sorts.

*Or you might if you reread a book, You would do this to all the pages*

> You are certainly reviewing the content of the book.

Comment: Revue isn't used for any of them